# тестирование сервлетов mockito

Tags: servlet, mockito

есть у меня сервлет и в doPost приходит запрос request
естественно я просто создаю объект сервлета и создаю объект реквеста и респонса

```
        MegaServlet servlet = new MegaServlet();
        HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse res = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        when(req.getParameter("att1")).thenReturn("0");
        when(req.getParameter("att2")).thenReturn("2");
        when(req.getParameter("att3")).thenReturn("3");
        servlet.doPost(req, res);
```

и вот при запуске метода пост у меня падает ошибка нулл поинтер екцепшен
дел в том что у меня в методе doPost  вызывается такая строчка:
 req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/qwe/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);   - и вот это падает с ошибкой нулл походу когда сервер не работает это req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/qwe/index.jsp") возвращает null (я в консоль это даже выводил)
а как ожно сделать чтобы эта строчка тоже возвращала что нить кроме нула или как то игнорировалась при тестировании?

Answer (score 0):

```
  RequestDispatcher disp = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);
  when(this.req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/qwe/index.jsp")).thenReturn(this);
```